# Bank money market account vs. Brokerage money market fund

Tags: united-states, brokerage, money-market

I would like to ask about the differences between BMM's and Brokerage money market funds (besides one being an account and the other being a fund). What are the pro's and con's of one and the other?
I have read about them but I am afraid the information I am reading is biased.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number one difference is that bank savings accounts, or money market accounts (MMAs allow limited checking--six non-ATM withdrawals per month, max, else possible fees) have FDIC insurance up to $250,000.  However don't put that much in--allow some room for interest, so you never go over the $250,000.  Money Market Mutual Funds do *not* enjoy FDIC insurance.  There may be some SPIC insurance--generally against brokerage failure though, but its coverage is questionable--search out those details, and if they apply to anything besides actual cash held at the brokerage.  ***If*** the money market mutual fund is strictly invested in US Treasury securities (like T-Bills, or other short-term US Treasury instruments), it enjoys the full faith and credit of the US government, FWIW--but many MMMFs invest in corporate instruments.  If the fund has any pricing issues, there might be a delay in getting paid off.  (Extremely unlikely.)
     Number two, *and more importantly*, bank savings accounts (or MMAs) pay way more!  You *can* get a bit over 1% APY now--many paying 0.90% APY, or higher.  No money market mutual funds are close to that, generally yielding a small fraction of that, almost zero for US Treasury MMM funds.  Sure 1.05% ain't too exciting, but you may as well get the most you can if holding "cash," and fully insured to boot.